# How to set the visibility of a rectangle in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm having some difficulty implementing the visibility of a rectangle and I used this line of code to set the visibility:

```
=IIF(Len(ReportItems!txtCountVolunteer.Value) > 0, true, false)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day to you as well.

It seems like that you have got the logic reversed in the expression. There is "Hidden" property for a rectangle, and note that there is no "Visible" property. So the expression for the rectangle's "Hidden" property should be:

```
=IIF(Len(ReportItems!txtCountVolunteer.Value) <= 0, true, false)
```